# Progress bar progression based on lines in file

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm trying to increase the Progress bar inside a foreach loop based on the number of lines processed in a file but it doesn't seem to work, not sure why maybe my maths is off?

Example of code

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
size = lines.Length;
int progress = 100 / size;

foreach (var line in lines){
      progressBar1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { 
             progressBar1.Value += progress; 
      });
}
```

Comment: @Bahrom just a Thread wrapper

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: @xdecdec the progress bar

Comment: No your maths is not off, it should work with this calculation. Do it work if you use `progressBar1.Value += progress;`  without the `BeginInvoke`

Comment: Make sure, if lines are read by `foreach` loop. try to console them

Comment: Why is `progress` an `int`?

Comment: @FCin because Progress.Value is a integer

Comment: @Presi wont work without a invoke due to progressbar being created in a seperate thread

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I will read through, within a split second of skimming the question, I saw something that may work for my use. Thanks

Comment: so what does change here? the amount of files alias `size`? you say " it doesn't seem to work" please be more precise. What is the actual outcome?

Comment: Managed to fix this by simply removing progress integer & applying progressBar1.maximum = size; & then setting progressBar1.Value += 1;

Comment: why should the amount of lines change?

Comment: @MongZhu the amount of lines don't change, but the value of the progressbar should change each loop which is equal to the amount of lines. However by default progressbar is set to 100 & if the amount of lines exceed 100, therefore the loop exceeds 100 & then the value of progressbar will exceed 100 and throw a exception, along with showing a inaccurate progress.

Comment: very nice, why isn't all this information inside your post. ;) next time it really should be. It makes all our lifes easier. And much easier to help you. Glad to hear that you solved your problem. Hint aside: if performing such calculations : `int progress = 100 / size;` don't forget the case where the line is empty and `size == 0`. Happy coding